# How to initalize array of size in vhdl

Tags: arrays, vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to initialize the VHDL array of size 4 with all zeros. Please let me know how can I do that?

```
entity js is
   port (
        clk: in std_logic;                      ----------  clock
        S1_vec : in  t_1d_array;                ----------  S1 vector/array of cross-section 4 [0 0 0 0]
        S2_vec : in  t_1d_array;                ----------  S2 Vector/array of cross-section 4 [0 0 0 0]
        J_outp : out integer            
        );
end js;
```

Comment: Without showing the declaration of `t_1d_array` type we cannot tell you how to initialise it.

Comment: `package mult_2x2_pack is

   type t_1d_array is array(0 to 3) of integer;

end  mult_2x2_pack;`

Comment: then this can be initialised simply by assigning 4 ints: `S1_vec : in  t_1d_array := (0,0,0,0);` As this is an input, it will only be assigned all 0s if the port is left unconnected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if we have a bigger size of array `type t_1d_array is array(0 to 299) of integer;`? How can we initialize them?

Comment: `:= (others => 0);`